# How remove geometry vertexes on hover OpenLayers 3+

Tags: openlayers

I am using `modify` interaction and would like to be able to delete vertexes by either clicking `delete + mouse` on the vertex or `delete + hover` vertex. `delete + mouse` works, `delete + hover` does not as `this.dragSegments_` is empty when accessed in `removeVertex_` therefore it results in point I am hovering over not being deleted.

Taken from `Modify.js`

```
removeVertex_() {
    this.gdFeaturesNotEdited = [];
    const dragSegments = this.dragSegments_;
    const segmentsByFeature = {};
    let deleted = false;
    ...
```

Only places I see `this.dragSegments_` being populated are `handleDownEvent` and `insertVertex_`. From the naming of the variable and functions it seems to me that vertex deletion on hover is not something that was designed to happen in OpenLayers 3+.

```
var modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: selectCtrl.getFeatures(),
    deleteCondition: function(event) {
        var deletePressed = keys['46']; // 46 = delete key 
        var isDeleteAction = event.type == 'pointermove' || event.type == 'pointerdown';

        return deletePressed && isDeleteAction ; 
    }   
});
```

Code that needs to be modified in TomazicM's answer to work with linear ring start/end coordinate deletion:

```
...
if (dist <= 8) {
    selectedCoord = coord[k];
    coord.splice(k, 1);

    // if deleting a coordinate at index 0 then coordinate at index coord.length - 1 will also be deleted because this is a coordinate that "opens" and "closes" linear ring
    // need to handle this by creating a new "closing" coordinate
    if (k == 0) {
        coord.splice(coord.length - 1, 1);
        coord.push(coord[0]); // creating new "closing" coordinate by duplicating first coordinate in array
    }

    setTimeout(updateGeometry, 150, feature, coord);
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come to the same conclusion that `deleteCondition` option does not offer possibility to delete vertex by hover. `removePoint()` method seemed like a good candidate, but for it to work point has to be selected and this can be done only by click.

However there is workaround by using `deleteCondition` function to check if mouse point is close enough to any of the feature points. If such point is found and delete key is down, point is removed from coordinates array and feature geometry is updated. Updating is done with slight delay of 0.5 second. This is the grace period to move cursor away so that ponint is no deleted. Map `pointermove` event is used for movement check.

This is the code (tested in ol5):

```
var deleteDown = false;
var selectedCoord = null;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
  deleteDown = (evt.keyCode == 46);
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
  deleteDown = false;
});

var draw = new ol.interaction.Modify({
  source: source,
  pixelTolerance: 5,
  deleteCondition: function(e){
    if (!deleteDown || (selectedCoord != null)) return;
    var features = source.getFeatures();
    features.forEach(function(feature) {
      var coords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
      for (var j = 0; j < coords.length; j++) {
        coord = coords[j];
        for (var k = 0; k < coord.length; k++) {
          var p0 = e.pixel;
          var p1 = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coord[k]);
          var dist = pointsDist(p0, p1);
          if (dist <= 8) {
            selectedCoord = coord[k];
            coord.splice(k, 1);
            setTimeout(updateGeometry, 500, feature, coord);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
map.addInteraction(draw);

map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
  if (selectedCoord == null) return;

  var p0 = e.pixel;
  var p1 = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(selectedCoord);
  var dist = pointsDist(p0, p1);
  if (dist > 8) selectedCoord = null;
});

function pointsDist(p0, p1) {
  var dx = p0[0] - p1[0];
  var dy = p0[1] - p1[1];        
  return (Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy));
}

function updateGeometry(feature, coord) {
  if (selectedCoord == null) return;
  feature.getGeometry().setCoordinates([coord]);
  selectedCoord = null;
}
```

Comment: Your solution has a problem when coordinate being deleted is first/last coordinate in array because in that case linear no longer has a correct linear ring start and end coordinate. See code change that needs to be made in my question

Comment: Answer was meant to be more as a proof of concept, not as final bulletproof solution. On rigorous testing that probably wouldn't be the only shortcoming.

Comment: I see:) You could update your code so that the case of linear ring start/end coordinate would be covered in same place as original code